# Pointer stored in array changes value C++

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers

First of all, I am noob at C++ so there is a huge chance I am making a stupid mistake. However I cannot figure out what the issue is.

I have an object class called `State` and I have created a custom class called `List` to store, add and remove pointer references of instances of the `State` objects.

Here is how the `List` class looks right now:

```
class List
{
    // VARIABLES
    private:
        State* list[];
    public:
        int length;
        
    // CONSTRUCTOR
    List()
    {
        length = 0;
    }
    
    // Add elements to list
    void add(State* s)
    {
        list[length] = s;
        
        cout<<length<<" "<<list[length]<<endl; // Print the recently added element

        length++;
    }
    
    // Print all the elements in the array
    void show()
    {
        cout<<endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            cout<<list[i]<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the code I have in my `main` function:

```
int main()
{   
    // Initialize States
    State s1 = State();
    State s2 = State();
    State s3 = State();
    
    // Initialize List
    List open = List();
    
    // Print Original Addresses of States
    cout<<&s1<<endl;
    cout<<&s2<<endl;
    cout<<&s3<<endl;
    
    // Add Addresses to List
    cout<<endl;
    open.add(&s1);
    open.add(&s2);
    open.add(&s3);
    
    // Loop over list to print addresses
    open.show();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
0x70fad0
0x70fbe0
0x70fcf0

Element added at index 0 : 0x70fad0
Element added at index 1 : 0x70fbe0
Element added at index 2 : 0x70fcf0

0x30070fad0
0x70fbe0
0x70fcf0
```

The addresses of the State objects and the addresses added to the list are all same, but when looping over the list to show the addresses, the first address is `0x30070fad0` instead of `0x70fad0` while the rest are all okay!

I cannot figure out why that is.

Comment: `State* list[];` is not valid C++

Comment: Even if that declaration was valid, C++ doesn't have dynamic arrays. If you want a dynamic array you need `std::vector`.

Comment: Your code is operating under the assumption that you can add values to `list` even though no memory has been allocated for it. I doubt that is true, although since `State* list[];` is not legal C++, it's hard to be sure.

Comment: And to be clearer...you are not allocating any space for your `State*`'s.  Use:  `State **list; ... list = new State*[max_num_objects];`

Comment: What can I do to create an array that stores pointer references for the object State then?

Comment: Again, use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: If I could I would. It's an assignment haha

Comment: @AhmedMustafa To create a dynamic array use a pointer and `new[]`, to create a dynamic array of pointers, use a pointer to a pointer, e.g. `State** list; list = new State*[size];`

Comment: Depending on what you want to do with your "List" object, it might be better suited to be a [linked list](https://www.learn-c.org/en/Linked_lists), since you can add objects to the tail with O(1) every time.

Comment: The syntax `State *list[]` is not valid for a class member although it works in **function parameters**. Same would be true for `int *a` vs `int a[]`. Then as other already pointed out, you must allocate memory for a dynamic array (or use a fixed size array instead that has a size big enough).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, you received some comments. I'm going to put them together into a full answer. This is your main problem:

```
    State* list[];
```

This is bad code, but it sounds like your compiler is letting you do it. This is suggesting you have an array of State-pointers. Great.

How big is the array?

Answer: unknown. We don't know how much space you're trying to take up.

C++ doesn't have dynamic arrays like Java (and other language) has. You can't just grow an array. The proper way to do this is to:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<State *> list;
```

That will require you to understand how to use std::vector.

The old-school (now outdated) method is to use a pointer to a pointer:

```
State ** list = nullptr;
int allocated = 0;
int length = 0;
```

Then, your add code needs to see:

```
if (length >= allocated) {
   // More space is required
    allocated += 16;  // or whatever size you want to grow by
    State ** newList = new State *[allocated];
    for (int index = 0; index < length; ++index) {
         newList[index] = list[index];
    }
    delete[] list;
    list = newList;
}
```

This is a pain in the ass, error-prone, and subject to memory leaks, which is why using std::vector is better.

Note also that dealing with pointers themselves is dangerous, and you should look at smart pointers besides.